# Можно ли в искомый массив добавить координаты найденных слов?

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ, анализатор

Например, есть такие массивы:

```
$a = array("
program {var} begin end
");

$b = Array
(
[oper] => Array
(
[0] => program
[1] => var
[2] => begin
[3] => end
)
[ogran] => Array
(
[0] => {
[1] => }
)
```

и чтобы вывод был таким:

```
program(oper,0), {(ogran,0), var(oper,1), }(ogran,1), begin(oper,2), end(oper,3)
```

Comment: Вам нужен по сути lex.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, там надо использовать Си, а тут же требуется PHP

Answer (score 1):

Я в свое время наткнулся на данный продукт [PHPPHP](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP) (да, это PHP исполняемый при помощи PHP) и сей продукт использует [PHP-Lexer](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser). Может быть он (PHP-Lexer) и не совсем то что нужно, но может навести на правильные решения и подходы